# Why does Distal of "yon" got no Source, Goal, Time, Manner, Reason?

Tags: old-english

I know [yon](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yon) is old-fashioned and bygone. [But why blanks in red rectangle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form#Table_of_correlatives) Why it had no Pro-adverb for Source, Goal, Time, Manner, Reason?

[image]

Comment: The 'distal' class (what's left of it) has now subsumed the medial, and these are considered sufficient. And with time, say, events can in the first instance be referenced by now or one other fixed point (then, with deixis). 'Later than then', 'before now' etc are used, but how could an event be '_more_ then'? Thenner?

Comment: I assume it might be for the same reason that English doesn't have, nor had, a single word for the middle child of the youngest brother of the second wife of my grandfather: there never was enough of a reason for anyone to invent such a word. And even the distal forms that _did_ exist have fallen into disuse, which might hint at the fact that English speakers don't consider a distal a very useful part of the language at all.